# Sets of natural numbers which are almost closed under addition

Tags: nt.number-theory, additive-combinatorics

I am interested in a classification of sets $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $k \in A$, $d( A+k \cap \mathbb{N} \setminus A) = 0$ where $d$ is the asymptotic density and $A+k = \{n \in \mathbb{N} : n-k \in A\}$. Sets with this condition are in a sense almost closed under addition. Some examples are sets of the form $C \setminus N$ where $C$ is closed under addition and $N$ has density $0$. Any set of density $0$ or $1$ also satisfies this property.

I hoped this condition was equivalent to $d(A \triangle C) = 0$ for some set $C$ closed under addition, but $A = 2 \mathbb{N} \cup \{1\}$ is a counterexample.

Is there some nice additive combinatorics classification of such sets?

Question also posted [here](http://www.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1690710/).

Comment: This is not exactly an answer, but two (hopefully helpful) remarks.
1) The set of $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ (not necessarily from $A$!) such that $d((A+k) \cap \mathbb{N} \Delta A)=0$ is an additive group. Thus, your condition holds if and only if it holds for a particular value of $k$ that is the gcd of all the elements of $A$.
2) Here is a counterexample: take a set $A$ that consists of all numbers not <i>starting</i> with the "7" digit. For any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ the addition of $k$ has almost no chances of changing the first digit, so it satisfies your condition.

Comment: I don't think there is much more to say than what @VictorKleptsyn has said. By scaling we may assume that the gcd of all the elements of $A$ is 1. Then the condition is equivalent to saying that the set of $x$ such that $x\in A$ and $x + 1 \notin A$ has density zero.